# $\mathbf{Field}$ subcategory of $\mathbf{Vec}$, $\mathbf{Ring}$ subcategory of $\mathbf{Mod}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, category-theory

Since every field $\Bbbk$ is a vector space over itself, and every commutative ring $R$ with identity is a module over itself, is it true that one can embed $\mathbf{Field}$ into $\mathbf{Vec}$?

Consider the functor $F: \mathbf{Field} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Vec}$ defined by the mapping $R \mapsto M_R$, where $M_R$ is the (bi) module of $R$ over itself.

The question is fairly elementary, and my concern to why it would not be true is because this seems like an immensely useful result, yet I haven't seen anybody state it explicitly.

To give a bit of (maybe unnessecary) context: The question comes from Noetherian rings, with their usual three equivalent definitions: satisfying the ascending chain condition, every non-empty partially ordered set of ideals has a maximum, and every ideal is finitely generated. Noetherian modules are defined similarly. My problem is that finitely generated is a property of modules, so one would have to "get out of"/"jump between" categories to make the last equivalence for rings. So my idea was to prove the equivalence for Noetherian modules and regard the equivalence for Noetherian rings as a special case.

Thank your very much in advance!

Comment: Endomorphisms of the field $k$ need not be $k$-linear, so you can't embed the morphisms this way.

Comment: An example of Tobais' claim is the conjugation automorphism of the complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thank you, I didn't keep that in mind.

Comment: I think for the application to the definition of Noetherian ring it would still make sense to prove the equivalence for modules and then regard the equivalence for rings as a special case, wouldn't it?

Comment: On the other hand, $R$ is (right) Noetherian iff $R_R$ is a Noetherian module, so your goal is still achievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category of vector spaces over arbitrary fields mixes both morphisms of vector spaces and of the fields they’re over, and isn’t much used in elementary contexts, although it and its relatives have great applications later on. Anyway, it doesn’t work for this purpose, as described in the comments. Normally one uses the category of vector spaces over a fixed field.

You could map the category of characteristic $p$ fields, where $p$ is prime or $0$, into the category of vector spaces over the corresponding prime field, $\mathbb{Z}/p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ as the case may be, since every field morphism is linear over the prime field, and do something similar with rings. But this isn’t particularly interesting-it’s just a slight refinement of the embedding of these categories into abelian groups, which is certainly a bit of a yawn. More common, as was mentioned in the comments, is to study properties of a ring that arise from its canonical module structure over itself, which doesn’t involve embedding any categories.

Comment: I don't agree that these things aren't interesting. The category $\mathsf{Mod}$ (and its generalizations) is a natural target for TFTs for example.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Of course. I didn’t say that the category of modules isn’t interesting, but that the embedding of rings in it isn’t.

Comment: It's the identity of $2$-morphisms...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry, what?

Comment: Consider the $2$-category $\mathsf{BiMod}$ whose objects are rings, morphisms are $(A,B)$-bimodules, and $2$-morphisms are bimodule maps. Then $A$ is the unit of the $A \to A$ morphisms. And since OP considers commutative rings, then an $A$-module is automatically an $(A,A)$-bimodule. Anyway. It's certainly a "trivial" case, but trivial cases aren't uninteresting...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Gotcha. Yeah, again, I don’t want to claim that it’s not useful to think of a ring as a module over itself, but that the particular embedding of all rings into all modules I described here isn’t of much use. I don’t think this shows up in your example, although it seems I was unclear about the scope of my claim.